# Putting "Curing Salt # 1" on a steak

Tags: seasoning

Is it safe to include a small pinch of "curing salt # 1" to a steak, and leave it at room temperature for 15 - 120 minutes before searing?

Comment: Usually curing salts are handled by % weight vs the thing being cured… but you’re getting into the territory of asking medical advice, which is off topic here

Comment: It's not medical advice, it's food safety advice. "Is it safe to do X" is a food handling question.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas : check the revision history.  There was mention of doing this as self medicating and possible side effects

Comment: If it was in the question then, but not now, it's irrelevant. As it stands the question is fine.

Comment: What would be the purpose of adding a pinch of curing salt to your steak before searing?  Curing salt #1 or #2 are not seasonings.

Comment: @moscafj see the revision history if you want to see why they’re asking this

Comment: @Joe...didn't see that coming.

Comment: Dear god... that myth was debunked decades ago!

Comment: To curb your unexpected arousal, it is better to follow [Ned Flanders' advice](https://frinkiac.com/meme/S08E06/330996/m/ICggZ2FzcHMpOiBDT1JOU1RBUkNIISBPSCwKIFJJR0hUWS1PSCEgSVQnUyBHT09EIEZPUgogS0VFUElORyBET1dOIFRIRSBVUkdFUy4=) and sprinkle cornstarch instead of sodium nitrate.

Answer (score 8):

[Here is the USDA full breakdown of how to use Nitrates. Nowhere does it say you can use curing salts as a finishing salt. I would always use Nitrates as directed by trusted recipes.](https://www.fsis.usda.gov/sites/default/files/media_file/2021-03/fplic-5a-cured-meat-and-poultry-operations.pdf)

## Maximum ingoing limits (In parts per million) for Poultry and Meat Products.

[image: Table of Nitrate Usage]

As a general rule of thumb you would use 1.13 grams of nitrates per pound of meat or 2.5 grams per KG of meat. With the addition of 1.59 grams per pound of meat or 3.5 grams of nitrates per KG for a brine.

If you just throw Curing salt on the Lord's mercy on food only God knows what will happen but probably nothing good. Curing salts are often coloured pink so that they are not mistaken for regular salt as using them like regular salt would be disasterous.

Comment: Agreed on not using it as a finishing salt.  There’s a chemical reaction that happens with the pink salt during curing, as the sodium nitrite turns into other compounds.  See https://www.thespruceeats.com/pink-salt-using-nitrates-to-cure-meat-1447029